# Should I set every WinForm object, such as textbox or button, public? What are the risks?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have noticed for high demand in my projects for objects such as textboxes or buttons public.

Is there any problems by setting them public?

What does public, private, static really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

public

> The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same
>   assembly or another assembly that references it.

private

> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or
>   struct.

protected

> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or
>   struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

internal

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly,
>   but not from another assembly.

protected internal

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in
>   which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another
>   assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class
>   declaration that derives from the class in which the protected
>   internal element is declared, and it must take place through an
>   instance of the derived class type.

There is no security risk as far as I know. But there may be better alternative approach to design your program

Comment: Is there any security risks? By enabling buttons seems innocent. But is it?

Comment: That says what the access modifiers *are* but doesn't give any *advice* which is what the question really seemed to be able.

Comment: There is no security risk as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

`public`, `private`, etc are called [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and determine the rules for which other code are allowed to access each member.

There is no technical problem of setting controls as public. But I would not recommend it. Having everything public is a good recipe for creating spaghetti code.

Keep all access to controls within your form and expose only a small set of public methods with a simple interface for external actors to access data and operations on the form.

Answer (score 3):

You should not, for a clean design.

You should in reality put the logic of your application outside forms!
However, if you want to keep logic inside forms, you should at least expose them with public properties and methods, without giving direct access to form controls.

For example you can provide things like a method "EnableSave" or "QuitApplication" or "UpdateState".

Answer (score 2):

Public, private and static deal with scope and what can talk to the objects / methods

`Public` -> Other classes can create an instance of your class (assuming the class is `public`) and call this object / method directly

`Private` -> Other classes can create an instance of your class (assuming the class is `public`) but can NOT access this object / method

`Static` -> Other classes can directly access this object / method (assuming class is `public` and method is `public static`) such as: `YourClassName.ObjectOrMethod` without having to create an instance of `YourClassName`

Answer (score 1):

The best access modifier to give to a gui component when you want to access it directly is :**internal** (that is the default in VB.NET for example).

However you shouldn't give a public or internal modifier on a GUI control and you shouldn't access it directly, because the presentation layer and business logic layer should be kept separated in a well designed architecture ...

Comment: Ok, well then. I have a main form, MainForm has a button save and add entry. Add entry form adds data to mainforms textbox. then save has to be blocked until there is an entry in main forms textbox. so addentry form has to have a privilege to access mainform save button to make it available. Does it require mainform save button to be public?

Comment: I don't understand your implementation ... However if you need to access directly a control of another form it is better the internal modifier rather than public...